# How to separate CustomUI tags in Excel-DNA from OnAction methods?

Tags: excel-dna

In my .dna file I have:

```
<DnaLibrary Name="First Add-In" RuntimeVersion="v4.0" Language="C#">
  <ExternalLibrary Path="MyLibrary.dll" Pack="true"/>  
  <Image Name="M" Path="M.png" Pack="true" />
  <CustomUI>
    <customUI xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui' loadImage='LoadImage'>
      <ribbon>
        <tabs>
          <tab id='CustomTab' label='My 2010 Tab'>
            <group id='SampleGroup' label='My Sample Group'>
              <button id='Button1' label='My Second Button' image='M' size='normal' onAction='RunTagMacro' tag='ReformatSelection='/>
            </group >
          </tab>
        </tabs>
      </ribbon>
    </customUI>
  </CustomUI>  
</DnaLibrary>
```

In my .cs file I have:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ExcelDna.Integration;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using ExcelDna.Integration.CustomUI;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyLibrary
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class Class1 : ExcelRibbon
    {                

        public void ReformatSelection(IRibbonControl control)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello");
        } 
    }
}
```

When I load the addin the button and tab appears fine in the Ribbon, but clicking the button does not run the ReformatSelection method. In the example files provided with Excel-DNA all the subs and functions that are hooked to the onAction events are in the .dna file. I am trying to move them out of the .dna file and into the .cs file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The same question also discussed here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/exceldna/mMBjb4xvH4k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your signature for `ReformatSelection()` is not right for the `onAction` handler of a ribbon button.

It should be:

```
public void ReformatSelection(IRibbonControl control) {...}
```

You can get a list of all the Office Ribbon callbacks signatures here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Hi Govert, I've tried that too but still no luck. I've edited my original post to show exactly what my code looks like now.

Comment: But now you've changed the ribbon xml markup too. It should work with your original version of the .xml markup, but the corrected callback signature. (Though the "onAction" tag name might be case sensitive.)